# Netbeans can´t deploy a Java web application with TomEE plus 1.7.1 on windows 10

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, netbeans, apache-tomee

I have this problem and I can´t solve it.. netbeans 8.0.2 can´t deploy a Java Web Application with TomEE Plus 1.7.1 server. I´ve tried with another server and it works (Tomcat 8.0.15.0 for example) but I can´t use it because I need TomEE for RESTful web services.
The problem when I try to run the applicaction the error is the next:

```
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Tomcat server started.
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Gilbert\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Prem\build\web
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FGilbert%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext644445905444534523.xml&path=/Prem
http://localhost:80/manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FGilbert%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext644445905444534523.xml&path=/Prem
C:\Users\Gilbert\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Prem\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1046: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 45 seconds)
```

Note, apparently the server is running but when I go to localhost:80/ (this is the port I choose) it shows an error 404.

help me please, thanks

Comment: What does the server log say?

Comment: There is error on your build process. Check the log and provide the information that happens when your are trying to deploy.

Comment: You need to check the Tomcat localhost log file and provide the exception/error details.

Comment: do you mean this? the file localhost_access_log.2015-11-10 file?